# svg to woff font

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, svg, woff

I have an SVG font file that is exactly how I want it. When I run it through a converter though (http://onlinefontconverter.com/), the output WOFF file displays different in Chome vs IE9. In IE9, the vertical alignment of the font is off (if I set `font-size:100px;line-height:100px;` it looks fine in Chrome, but in IE9 the top of the glyphs are chopped off).

Is this a problem with IE9 incorrectly displaying WOFF files, or is there more to it than that?

I did a test where I converted my Courier New TTF file into WOFF, and it displays fine in both browsers. When I take the Courier New SVG, however, and convert that to WOFF, the same display issue arises.

Thanks!

EDIT: The display issue also occurs with EOT files and in IE10. It seems to me like there is some issue converting SVG -> WOFF, but I don't know much about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE < 9 you should use EOT files. WOFF is for modern browsers. The [FontSquirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) is really helpful for this and will give you the @font-face kit too.

Comment: sorry, i shouldve mentioned that the problem occurs with EOT files and also in IE10.

Comment: i just tried fontsquirrel and it seemed to convert the font correctly. thanks!

Comment: Oh dear, since June 2012 they don't support SVG fonts.  http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2012/06/svg-support-in-the-generator

Comment: MDN tells me WOFF should work in IE 9, so maybe change that <= to < ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Browser_compatibility